# Datatable don't refresh

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Good evening from Sweden!

I try to get a primefaces datatable to refresh. I tried various hints and solutions but nothing is working. 
The button triggers a search in the DB and if I refresh the paga manually or if I use the tables sorting-function the result is shown. 
Means the code in the backing bean works. But no automatic refresh directly after the button is clicked..
The bean scope is Session.

Here is the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <h:head>
  </h:head>
<h:body>


<ui:composition template="/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
<h:form id="src_res">
 <h2>Sök klass,undervisningsgrupp eller individ</h2>                     

            <b>Sökord</b>: &nbsp;<h:inputText  id="sw" value="#{smsb.searchword}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Lärare"></p:outputLabel>
            <h:selectOneListbox size="1" id="teacher" value="#{smsb.searchteacher}" >
            <f:selectItems  value="#{smsb.teachers}"/>
            </h:selectOneListbox>
            <p:commandButton action="#{smsb.searchgrp_user}" value="Sök!"   update="src_list"/> 

<p:dataTable   id="src_list"    value="#{smsb.searchresult}"  var="obj" >    

                  <p:column width="20%" sortBy="#{obj.groupname}">
                      <f:facet name="header" >
                          <h:outputText value="Beteckning"/>
                      </f:facet>    
                      <h:outputText value="#{obj.groupname}"/>
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column width="10%">
                      <f:facet name="header" >
                          <h:outputText value="typ"/>
                      </f:facet>    
                      <h:outputText value="#{obj.klass}"/>
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column width="10%" sortBy="#{obj.teacher}">
                      <f:facet name="header" >
                          <h:outputText value="lärare"/>
                      </f:facet>    
                      <h:outputText value="#{obj.teacher}"/>
                  </p:column>
              </p:dataTable>
              </h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Any help or hints?

With regards
Ralf

**EDIT**

Hello and thanx for the offer to help!

As you guessed searchresult is a list and the Getter is defined by

```
List<sbasUserList> searchresult;    

public List<sbasUserList> getSearchresult() {
    return searchresult;
}
```

search_grp is a method of the backing bean:

```
public String searchgrp_user(){



    //FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 

    ObjectContainer db = this.connBD("sms");
    ObjectSet<sbasUserList> res;

    this.searchresult = new ArrayList<sbasUserList>() ;

    Query query=db.query();
    query.constrain(sbasUserList.class);
    query.descend("groupname").constrain(this.searchword).like();
      query.descend("type").constrain('P').or(query.descend("type").constrain('M'));
    query.descend("teacher").constrain(searchteacher).contains();       
    res = query.execute();
    this.searchresult.addAll(res);
    System.out.println(this.searchresult.size());
    db.close();
    return "";
}
```

The table is filled with the right dat if i update manually the browser. (F5) but certainly would like to have this done automatically.

Comment: Am I right that "Sök!" is the search-button? What is `smsb.searchresult`, an action or just a list? If List, are you sure that the value changes after calling `smsb.searchgrp_user`? If it is an action, what is it doing?

Comment: Hey Ralf can you show come of the bean code?

Comment: @user1983983 : I updated my question with some relevant code.

Comment: Try to return `null` in `searchgrp_user` or to set the return type to `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks! The glassfish server I was using wasn't setup right. It showed not all of the errors in the log file. I did a complete new setup of the whole IDE (new Eclipse, new glassfish server, thanx BalusC for the incredible tutorial!!!) and I found all errors. Now it works like it should!

Regards
Ralf